# dbSNP database table desciptions

Tags: bioinformatics, database

I am trying to build a local implementation of dbSNP. I would like to know the descriptions of tables listed on ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/snp/database/organism_data/human_9606 and on ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/snp/database/shared_data/. I tried to use the search on this webpage : http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/SNP/snp_db_list_table.cgi which is supposed to be a data dictionary for all tables and columns, but I think it is outdated. There are many tables which do not have any definition. Also, there are tables in this dictionary that are not in the ftp site at all. Does anyone know of any better dictionary for the dbSNP database tables?

Comment: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK3855/ ?